# What does "value | 0" mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've seen code like this

```
 v = Math.random() * 100 | 0;
```

What does the `| 0` mean?

Answer (score 4):

`value | 0` means "convert `value` to an integer"

`|` is the [bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR).

To work it first converts the values on both sides to signed 32bit integers then it does a bitwise OR of the values. Since bitwise OR with `0` does nothing this has the effect of just converting to an integer.

It is different that `Math.floor` in that it converts toward zero

```
          | Math.floor | Math.ceil | Math.trunc | | 0  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
   2.5    |     2      |     3     |     2      |   2  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
   1.5    |     1      |     2     |     1      |   1  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
   0.5    |     0      |     1     |     0      |   0  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
  -0.5    |    -1      |     0     |     0      |   0  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
  -1.5    |    -2      |    -1     |    -1      |  -1  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
  -2.5    |    -3      |    -2     |    -2      |  -2  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
 Infinity |  Infinity  |  Infinity |  Infinity  |   0  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
   NaN    |    NaN     |    NaN    |    NaN     |   0  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
 2**32+5  | 4294967301 |4294967301 | 4294967301 |   5  |
----------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
```

That last one, `2*32+5` is a value that does not fit in 32 bits to point out you need to know when `| 0` is appropriate and when it's not.

`| 0` is also significantly faster than `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`. There may be many reasons it's faster the most obvious is it's an operator, not a function on the Math object which can be replaced and therefore has to be checked on each usage.

It has [a very low precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) which means you can usually tack it on to the end of an expressions without parenthesis

```
 integerResult = someValue / someOtherValue | 0;
```

Comment: can you compare it to `int = ~~n`? is it the same? the same on negatives? thanks!

Comment: Well `~~v` is 2 operations where as `v | 0` is one operation. `| 0` is used extensively in `asm.js` so maybe it has been optimized though that's just speculation. But yea, ~~ seems to generate the same results. ~~ also requires parens `~~50/7` doesn't work where as `50/7|0` does